# Eliminar elemento repetidos JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jsonarray

Necesito mostrar este JSON en un innerHTML, pero con la condición de que los valores repetidos como la id o el nombre no aparezcan y solo salgan los únicos. He estado probando, pero no encuentro una manera de hacerlo. He probado este código, pero no funciona.

```
function noRepetir (){
var listArray ='[{"id":"a","nom":"joan"},{"id":"b","nom":"david"},{"id":"a","nom":"joan"},{"id":"c","nom":"pep"},{"id":"b","nom":"david"}]'
var uniquesArray =[];
var count = 0;
var found = false;
var text = document.getElementById("exercici5");
var obj= JSON.parse(listArray);

for(i=0;i<listArray.length;i++){
    for(y=0;y<uniquesArray.length;y++){
        if(obj[i].id == uniquesArray[y]){
            found=true;
        }
    }
    count++;
    if(count==1 && found==false){
        uniquesArray.push(obj[i].id);
    }
    count=0;
    found = false;
}

for(i=0;i<listArray.length;i++){
    text.innerHTML+="<br>"+obj[i].id;
}
```

}

Comment: En PHP tienes el método array_unique para obtener los elementos no repetidos de un array. Podrías buscar si hay algún equivalente en JavaScript y usarlo al principio, generar ese array único y luego recorrerlo directamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente.

Lo que hago es guardar en un objeto los valores que quieres que no se repitan y en cada iteración del loop comprobar que el `id` y `name` no existan en `itemsRepeated`. Si esta condición es cierta se añade el `item` al array `unique` y se añaden los valores de `id` y `name` en el objeto `itemsRepeated` para que no vuelva a repetirse. Sino, no se hace nada.

```js
var listArray = '[{"id":"a","nom":"joan"},{"id":"b","nom":"david"},{"id":"a","nom":"joan"},{"id":"c","nom":"pep"},{"id":"b","nom":"david"}]'

const data = JSON.parse(listArray);

const itemsRepeated = {};
const unique = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const item = data[i];
  if (!itemsRepeated[item.id] && !itemsRepeated[item.name]) {
    itemsRepeated[item.id] = item.id;
    itemsRepeated[item.name] = item.name;
    unique.push(item);
  }
}

const container = document.getElementById("exercici5");
const html = unique.map(item => `<p>Id: ${item.id}, Nom: ${item.nom}</p>`).join('');

container.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="exercici5"></div>
```

Para mostrarlo en el `html` puedes iterar todos los elementos únicos y crear el html con los datos.
Como `map` devuelve un array puedes hacer el `join` de los datos y formar un único string que contenga el html para asignarlo a `innerHTML`.

Comment: Como podria hacer que me lo pintase con un inner html ? Rollo La id: a es el nombre Joan. En vez de mostrar por console.log. Muchas gracias por cierto

Comment: he actualizado mi respuesta. Si te sirvió la respuesta aceptala.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar filter, y buscar tu elemento que este en la misma posicion que la que encuentres con findIndex

```js
var listArray = [{
  "id": "a",
  "nom": "joan"
}, {
  "id": "b",
  "nom": "david"
}, {
  "id": "a",
  "nom": "joan"
}, {
  "id": "c",
  "nom": "pep"
}, {
  "id": "b",
  "nom": "david"
}];


var datos = listArray.filter((data, index, j) => 
  index === j.findIndex((t) => (t.id === data.id && t.nom === data.nom))
)

console.log(datos);
```